# How to get either an existing document or newly added document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a table structure as given below.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6b8"), 
 "product" : "product1", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 1", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 1
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6b9"), 
"product" : "product2", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 2", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 2
}
    { 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6ba"), 
 "product" : "product1", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 1", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 2,
"added_by" : user1
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6bb"), 
"product" : "product2", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 2", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 1,
"added_by" : user1
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6bc"), 
"product" : "product3", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 3", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 3,
"added_by" : user1
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6bd"), 
"product" : "product4", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 4", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 4
}
```

I would like to explain the database structure first.

I have default products for every user on my website and users can add their own products to the list or they can re-order the existing list. when they add a new product it will be added by their username. when they re-order the products, I get the existing default records and insert by appending the username and change the order (you will understand that if you observe the above data).

Now how can I get the products for a category specific to a user.

For example if i need to get all the products for a user1 in category1 the output should be as below (sorted based on the order field). If you observe carefully the above data, the same product is been repeated with extra field named added_by and order changed. I want to get the order of user if user customizes it, If not the default order.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6bb"), 
"product" : "product2", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 2", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 1,
"added_by" : user1
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6ba"), 
 "product" : "product1", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 1", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 2,
"added_by" : user1
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6bc"), 
"product" : "product3", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 3", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 3,
"added_by" : user1
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6bd"), 
"product" : "product4", 
"title" : "Alt Summit 4", 
"category" : "category1", 
"order" : 4
}
```

I am open for any suggestion on if I should change the structure of the table. But at any given time I should be able to get to the output which I mentioned above.

Comment: `db.yourCollection.find({ "category": "category1", "added_by": "user1" }).sort({ "order": 1 })` should return the cursor that you're looking for, no?

Comment: No @Adam I should still get the default products if user hasn't re-ordered the objects. The above query will give me only user added products or user re-ordered products. If there is same product in same category both default and added by a user, I should then get user order along with other default products.

Comment: the default products are defined as those not having a `"added_by"` key? If so, then try `db.yourCollection.find({ "$or": [ { "category": "category1", "added_by": "user1" }, { "added_by": { "$exists": false } } ] }).sort({ "order": 1 })`

Comment: I worked on this query before @Adam. This gives me all the duplicates too. If a product is existing by default and added_by a user only the document which matches the current user should be projected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation with current Mongo 3.4 version.

`$match` documents for query criteria.

`$group` documents on `product` and pick the `$first` based on the earlier sort order while keeping the document with `$$ROOT`.

`$replaceRoot` to promote the `root` document to top level.

'$sort' by `order` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
    "category": "category1",
        $or: [{
            "added_by": "user1"
        }, {
            "added_by": {
                "$exists": false
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$product",
        "root": {
            "$first": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$root"
    }
},{
    $sort: {
        "order": 1
    }
}])
```

**Update after OP's Comment**

`$group` documents on `product` and `$push` all the products with `$$ROOT`.

`$project` stage to compare the `$size` if not `$eq` to 1 then `$filter` to pick the product with the `added_by` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "category": "category1",
        $or: [{
            "added_by": "user1"
        }, {
            "added_by": {
                "$exists": false
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$product",
        "products": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "product": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [{
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            $eq: [{$size: "$products"}, 1]
                        },
                        "$products", 
                        {
                            "$filter": {
                                input: "$products",
                                as: "product",
                                cond: {
                                    $ifNull: ["$$product.added_by", false]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                0
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$product"
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "order": 1
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Veeram. I see you are picking the first document out of two. But, Is there any way that I pick a document which has added_by field instead of picking the first or last element. I think for the structure I posted the solution you gave still works good. I am gonna check it anyway but it would be great if you could update with the change I mentioned in this comment.

Comment: You are welcome. I'll update the answer but i just need to understand it a little bit more. I think I made a mistake and should have picked the last product. The reason for picking the last was thinking that you'll have re-order product's order  after default product's order. So by sorting in the pipeline, I'll have the reorder product last. Is that not the case ? Can user pick order ?

Comment: In most of the cases yes we have to pick the last product. But I think I have a very different scenario which you haven't heard before. No mater what the order is I want to pick the product if it is added by a user inside a category. Because not just re-ordering the products the user may also add products to that category in that case there is a chance that the default product is sometime ahead or below the same product added by user. So in order to make this work I want it not based on first or last but I want to get the user added product either it may be before or after default product.

Comment: Please let me know if you still didn't get it. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear. I don't think we've any problem with adding new products. The issue is picking between default product and re-order product in the `$group` stage. Updated answer to take `added_by` field into consideration. Moved `$sort` to the end of pipeline.

Comment: Exactly. The updated query worked for my use case. Thank you very much.